# Cannot start mongodb server

Tags: mongodb

I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/), as well as [this one](https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/mongo-mac.html), and I keep getting the same error when starting up my mongodb server.

Running just `mongo` returns

```
zsh: command not found: mongod
```

Running `./mongod` returns

```
zsh: exec format error: ./mongod
```

Running `sudo ./mongod` returns

```
./mongod: ./mongod: cannot execute binary file
```

My mongodb folder is located in `~/mongodb`, which is where the `bin` folder is.  I also created the directory where Mongo will store the data in `/data/db`, with the correct permissions: `drwxr-xr-x`.  I don't know what I'm missing, or what I'm doing wrong.

**How do I start the mongodb server?**

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**

I was using the wrong OS.  I downloaded the linux version when I should have downloaded the OS X version since I'm on a Mac.  Once I did, everything worked fine.

Comment: Yes, be careful to select platform on available download

Answer (score 1):

Much more robust is if you start it as a service with `sudo service mongod start`

Alternatively, you need to make sure the directory is added to .bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

try this command. It worked for me in **git bash**

`./mongod.exe  --port <port number> --dbpath <db folder path>`

Ex:

`./mongod.exe  --port 27017 --dbpath E:/Projects/Databases/data/db`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the path to your MongoDB is not within your $PATH. If you are on linux you can quickly run:

```
echo $PATH
```

If it is not in your path, then you want to add it:

```
export PATH=/path_to_mongodb_bin/:$PATH
```

Once done, attempt to start mongodb by running:

```
mongod
```